# Find matrix commuting with all projections

Tags: matrices

Please help me solve this problem:

Find matrix $A$ such that $A$ commutes with all projection matrix (A matrix $P$ is said to be projection if $P^2 = P$).

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hint: such a matrix has to be diagonalizable in every basis, since it leaves every one-dimensional subspace invariant (as it commutes with the projection onto the latter).

Comment: I'm sorry, I should make it more clear. The problem requires us find ALL matrices $A$.It is not difficult to prove that $A$ must be a diagonal matrix by consider all matrices $P$ with only $i$-th ($i = 1, 2, \dots, n$) element in the diagonal being 1, all others being 0.

How to do next, could we prove that all diagonal matrices are solution or the matrices must have some other properties?

Comment: I understood the question, it is clear enough. My hint is supposed to let you conclude more than merely "diagonal". Basically you should note that $Ax=\lambda_x x$ for every vector $x$. Then prove that the scalar $\lambda_x=\lambda$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: @julien IMO, this should be an answer.

Comment: Excellent idea :). Thank you so much.